# (Objective-c) Text View "Clear When editing starts"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Is it possible to add Clear when editing starts to a text view? This option is available for the text field but I couldn't find anything for the text view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Implement the [`UITextViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextViewDelegate) method called `textViewDidBeginEditing:`, and inside of it, set the `text` property to an empty `NSString` object:

```
- (void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *) textView {
  [textView setText:@""];
  //other awesome stuff here...
}
```

Comment: does not work for me, implemented delegate, added this method but it does not get called for some reason unknown.

Answer (score 0):

above did not work for me, had to use notifications:

add notification in viewWillAppear:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(textViewDidBeginEditing:) name:UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
```

method to clear the current text view

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)notif{
UITextView *textView=notif.object;
textView.text=@"";
```

}

remove notification in viewWillDisappear:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
```

Hope it helps somebody